# Rely on PATH or provide an explicit path when using system()

Tags: c

I'm writing a 'C' program that makes several calls to system() to execute other programs. When constructing the command string is it better to explicitly give the full path to the program being called, or should I just give the executable name and let the shell resolve its location using the PATH environment variable?

The programs I'm calling are all part of a single package and I have the path to the installation directory from a preprocessor definition. Giving the explicit path would seem to avoid errors that might occur if multiple installed programs share the same name. However it makes building the command strings a little more complicated, and everything will break if the user moves the programs around after installation.

Is there a widely accepted best practice covering this?

[Clarification]

I'm using autoconf/automake to generate the distribuion. The preprocessor definition providing the installation directory is created by the makefile. It reflects the user's choice of the installation directory as specified either on the configure comamnd line or the make command line. I do take the point about using environment variables to specify the  location for the binaries though. It seems like an unneeded pain in the butt to make users rebuild just to change the location of the binaries.

Comment: Your install directory is in the wrong place for my machine...so make sure that the user can install the software where they want, not where you want (though you can certainly have a preferred or default location). And then allow for the choice in the processing.  You can reasonably assume your own software is all in the same place. You cannot assume that optional software is in the place you expect (though trying /bin and /usr/bin is probably reasonable). On my machines, /usr/local is NFS-mounted read-only by MIS and redolent with archaic software (Perl 4 vanished last year!). I use /usr/gnu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to not presume anything about the system you're installing onto.  You can have the best of both worlds if you just let the user choose.  Make the command you call an application preference or require paths to be defined in the environment:

```
PATH_TO_TOOL1=foo
PATH_TO_TOOL2=/usr/bin/bar
```

You can, of course, just fall back to a default of some kind if the variables aren't defined or the preference isn't set.  Writing your application to be more flexible is always the best choice!

Comment: Thanks very much. Others repeated your advice, and I thank them, but I think you were first to the mark, and the most explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is never to assume that you know your install directory at build time. Let your users decide where to install and work anyway.

This means that you will need to find out where your programs are located using some other mechanism. Consider using environment variables or command line parameters to allow the user to specify the actual path, if your platform does not provide you with the means to find out where the executables are located. You can use your knowledge of where you are normally installed as a fallback option.

For your actual question, in case you can build the absolute path to your program (using another mechanism than preprocessor directives) - use that. Otherwise, fall back to having the system find out for you.

Comment: I agree although he didn't say if the preprocessor macro was set by configure(1), for example (which would be bad), or by the makefile (which would be good).

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely let the user specify the path with an environment variable to the installed binaries. Not all systems are the same and many people will want to put their execs in different places.

the best example I can think of is people doing a local install vs system install. If your program is installed in a home directory that user will have to set and env variable to say where the binaries are copied to.

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely sure of the path names, and if they are not "well-known" commands (for example, POSIX shell utilities on Unix are "well-known"), you should specify the pathname, otherwise don't specify the full path, or let the user control it by using an environment variable.

In fact, you may be able to write something like a function such as `int my_system(const char *);`, which does the prefixing of the path for you.  If later you determine that it was a bad idea, it's just a matter of making `my_system()` identical to `system()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a best practice, but what I do in these cases is I write my C code to **extend the `PATH` environment variable to include the installation directory at the end**.  Then I just use the `PATH`.  That way, if the user's `PATH` wants to override where I believe the stuff was installed, it can—but if the software was installed in an out-of-the-way place, I can call it without forcing my users to put the directory on `$PATH` themselves.

Please note that the extended `PATH` lasts only as long as the C program runs; I'm not proposing changing the persistent `PATH`.

Comment: I sincerely hope that you only do that temporarily (I, personally, would never, ever, do it at all).  

It adds a small performance hit to *every* command issued (not just by you). And, of course, there is a limit to the length of the path (in windows, at least).  

I like a lean, mean PATH, preferably just o/s directories and I strongly dislike lazy programmers who add their directories to the path just because it makes things easier for them (and don't care what it does for me)

Comment: @mawg: Temporarily indeed.  I've edited my answer.  As far as the performance hit, you might notice it on a slow server, but it doesn't apply to every command, just to commands that (a) are called from this C program and (b) aren't found.  The change in `PATH` shouldn't be visible to the user of the C program.

Also, I'm guessing that you administer your own machine and have never had to deal with a BOFH who doesn't allow you to install in OS directories.  That's not laziness, it's fascism, but it's very real.